# Reconfiguring the DNS to show the SSL certificate online?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, dns

So, I am trying to get the SSL certificate to show up on my website but even after following all the steps from the aws documentation and various internet tutorials. The SSL lock sign is still not visible up on my website.

I found this website really helpful and tried to follow all the steps listed there : https://blog.webinista.com/2016/02/enable-https-cloudfront-certificate-manager-s3/index.html

What I think the problem is that I am not quite certain how to reconfigure the DNS server after creating the cloudfront distribution. In this instance, I just created an alias target for my domain name (shamveelahammed.com) to point towards the cloudfront distribution. But this hasn't worked at all for me. At the moment, I only have 4 entries in my domain record set.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g2nkyxip1c22oo/Screen%20Shot%202017-07-05%20at%2002.05.31.png?dl=0

Any help with figuring out my next steps will be massively appreciated. (N.B I am very new to this and still learning how to use AWS.)

Comment: I assume you have modified your web server side to force to port 443 when the request is made on port 80.

Comment: why did you put two alias records. That is one for cloudfront and other one is aliased to s3.

Comment: @Ali Well, I don't remember modifying the web server specifically to port 443 each time a request is made on port 80. Could you please tell me the implications of it and where do I have to change it?

Comment: @naveenkerati I created my first alias targeted to the s3 bucket (which included www in front ie. www.domain-name.com) to get website running, but in the above mentioned tutorial it suggested to create another alias targeted to the cloudfront distribution. So, I created the second alias.

Comment: @shamveel_ahammed i think you have restricted bucket access when creating cloudfront . So i think you  can remove that alias s3 alias record.And did you configured  certificate for both shamveelahammed.com and www.shamveelahammed.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thanks for all the helpful answers. I managed to find a work around to solve the issue I was having.

1. I generated a new certificate for the domain www.shamveelahammed.com .
2. Created a target alias for cloud distribution pointed towards www.shamveelahammed.com .
3. And finally, redirected all the requests made in www.shamveelahammed.com in s3 bucket to shamveelahammed.com.

This fixed my problem. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

As you have restricted bucket access when creating cloudfront .So you dont need the additional alias record for s3 in Route53. you have to generate certificate for both domains www.shamveelahammed.com and shamveelahammed.com OR you can generate wildcard certificate for your domain as *.shamveelahammed.com .

In your case it seems you have generated certificate only for www.shamveelahammed.com Domain only.

Comment: I generated a new certificate for shamveelahammed.com and tried removing the alias record of the s3. But after I remove it, the server stops working and I can't load my website any longer.  Do I need a create a second cloudfront distribution and use that newly generated ssl certificate? And should I still keep the 4 entries for the record set with the 2 aliases?

Comment: I can see that your website http://www.shamveelahammed.com/ is currently up . But it is serving http .Did you generated certificate for www.shamveelahammed.com domain too. And after generating certificate  updated it in cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

DNS isn't the issue.

In CloudFront, each Cache Behavior needs its [Viewer Protocol Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesViewerProtocolPolicy) configured for **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS**.